# How to get the UI look of a PreferenceScreen in Android without Using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, sharedpreferences

What I mean by this I currently have an app that stores data in an SQLlite database but I'm struggling to make the UI for a data entry (a fair number of fields on one screen) look anything good. Everything I do still looks simplistic and unstructured.

What I'd like to do is be able to do is make something that follows the style of the settings panel introduced in Honeycomb/ICS, I know you can create a preference screen but then the problem with that is it's designed to store straight to shared preferences right? and I want to store directly to rows in my database.

Is there away to generate a preference screen as a view but override the read/write of shared preferences? Or should I approach this more with a goal of just recreating the layout structure and styles? Would is make sense to use a ListView that uses different views for fields (seems slightly insane to me) displays each database field as a list item?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ListFragment that displays a condensed extract of one database row in the list and when the user clicks it switch to a different fragment that displays only that row but all of it.

Check [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) for pointers. Replace the Headlines with the partial row information (populating it from your DB instead of an array of course) and the article detail with the full row information.

Comment: Sorry I think you've missed the point that I was making, I understand the concept of UI, I'm actually talking about how to make a decent looking UI Input form that displays all the fields, I already have a list view that displays all the database rows but it's displaying all the text editors and optional settings that looks really dull

Comment: Indeed, it looks like I read too fast, my apologies. If you want to use Preferences you could use Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener but it would be called each time a preference is changed instead of when all changes are done so you might want to have it update the data somewhere in the PreferenceActivity and when it finishes commit it to the db, but it would still save the preferences to XML. If not just use a LinearLayout or GridLayout (API 14 or support lib v7) in a ScrollView, have them update a local copy and commit that when a save button is clicked. Why use a ListView?